# Google play Plants vs Zombies 2 android achievements I already completed

Tags: achievements, android, plants-vs-zombies-2, google-play-games

Several of the Plants vs Zombies 2 android achievements I already completed, e.g. complete Ancient Egypt, before the achievements in google play were introduced. Not only don't I have credit for those achievements, I can't complete them either. E.g. I just re-beat the last stage of Ancient Egypt, and still no achievement. Any ideas?

Edit: The only relevant source I can find with google would be the 1st comment here, which is not super encouraging: http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements_%28Plants_vs._Zombies_2:_It%27s_About_Time%29

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already beaten all the levels before the upgrade, you only need to complete the level *before* the last level in order to activate the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing since before the achievements were introduced, and suffered from the same issue. I believe the requirements for the achievement are to beat every single level, its just the variables required to get the achievement don't recognize you beating them all.

What I did to resolve it was to play through each map and beat each level again. Beating the levels should be relatively easy, especially since you have a ton more plants unlocked and zen garden first strike powerups (neither of which were available when first playing through ancient egypt).

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is already answered but i managed to get the world completion achievements i could not get, playing again the second to last level in the world(s). That means you've got to play the level before any zomboss battle in order to get locked achievements due to lack of internet connection.